# Is there a way to read parts of file while calculating checksum in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, checksum

I am trying to calculate the checksum of some iso files of size approx 10GB on a azure pipeline. But I am getting the following error "ExceptionType: System.IO.IOExceptionExceptionMessage: No space left on device ".

This is how I'm calculating the checksum.

```
public string SHA256CheckSum(string filePath)
{
    using (SHA256 SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create())
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        return Convert.ToString(BitConverter.ToString(SHA256.ComputeHash(fileStream)).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant());
    }
}
```

Is there a way that the checksum can be calculated in parts so that the pipeline doesn't run out of memory?

Comment: Why do you convert a string to a string?

Comment: *Is there a way that the checksum can be calculated in parts* Isn't `ComputeHash` with stream as parameter doing  this already?... Error is prolly no here

Comment: No space left is rather disk space problem not memory for me... That's why I wrote that the problem is not here

Comment: @Selvin that was my understanding as well, but what is consuming the disk space if file is already present on the disk, and is there a way around it ?

Comment: @Fildor my bad there, you are right not needed

Comment: This code itself isn't writing anything to disk, nor would it be likely to cause any writes from (e.g.) running out of committed virtual memory. Try replacing this code with `return ""` and see if things still fail -- I suspect they will, and the problem is rather when those 10 GB files need to be written themselves, or when they are implicitly copied around.

Comment: There is almost no chance the issue is in this code. The `ComputeHash` function is already streaming the data in, it will not cache it anywhere. Please show the full stack trace of your exception.